# Somehow Fermat's Last Theorem but not really

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Remember the equation
$(a)^n$ + $ (b)^n$ $\ne$ $ (c)^n$.
Well then, what would happen if we allow the powers $\textit{n}$ to be three distinct odd primes such that
$ (a)^{p1}$ + $ (b)^{p2}$ = $ (c)^{p3}$.
When we do that, can we find three integers $\textit{a}$, $\textit{b}$ and $\textit{c}$ satisfying the above equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematics on this site.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: It is a fun exercise to prove that in such a situation the solution will always exist, and in fact we may take $a,b,c$ to be powers of $2$.

Comment: Why restrict ourselves to $\textit{a}$,$\textit{b}$ and $\textit{c}$ being powers of 2? Why assume that, say, odd numbers (they aren't powers of 2) will never work and don't need to be considered?

Comment: @MugaS. You just asked whether examples exist, so one such example is enough to answer your question.

Comment: I'm surprised by the negative response to this question. It definitely has issues, but this seems too strong a reaction. While it's easy to answer the question as phrased - indeed, every Sophie Germain prime generates an example - it's easy to modify it so it becomes (apparently) nontrivial and (in my opinion) interesting.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am yet to see one such example. Basically, if someone could post values for $\textit{a}$, $\textit{b}$ and $\textit{c}$ and the other three distinct primes $\textit{p1}$,$\textit{p2}$ and $\textit{p3}$, that would be great.

Comment: Also, $1^5+2^3=3^2$.

Comment: $10^2+3^5=7^3$.

Comment: @MugaS. Per the comments above, every [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) yields such an example: if $p$ and $2p+1$ are both prime, then we have $$(2^2)^p+(2^p)^2=2^{2p+1}.$$ For example, $p=2$ yields $4^3+8^2=2^7$, $p=11$ yields $4^11+(2^{11})^2=2^{23}$, and so forth. So examples were implicit in the comments above. (And Torsten Shoeneberg and mathlove above gave answers not falling into this pattern.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Edited the question to "distinct ODD primes" so the 2 won't work.

Comment: It is related to the abc conjecture https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture

Comment: see beal's conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just stealing Wojowu's answer

Let $r$ be an inverse of $p_3$ modulo $p_1p_2$ let $m=rp_3-1$ then a solution is 
$$(2^{m/p_1})^{p_1}+(2^{m/p_2})^{p_2} = (2^{(m+1)/p_3})^{p_3}$$

I don't know about the problem when we restrict to $a,b,c$ coprime, I'm quite sure there exist modifications making the problem as hard as Fermat last theorem.

Comment: Indeed, it would be quite interesting to hear the various modifications for this problem.